# Is this a Double Post?

Tags: discussion, support

As I continue to earn more privileges through reputation gains, I'm beginning to broaden my posting knowledge.  While watching the Review/Late Answers queue, I thought I'd check the list, and ran into this:

[Enabling Telnet on the NETGEAR N300 Wi-Fi Gigabit Router (WNR3500L) Possible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155081/netgear-n300-model-no-d1500-telnet).

In the process of researching for an answer, I found that he had already posted the question at:

[The OpenRouter Forum - Same Question](http://www.myopenrouter.com/forum/thread/56796/NETGEAR-N300-Model-No.-D1500-telnet-help/)

Someone Else cleaned up his Bolding mess, and I fixed the title after finding the correct model.  Is this considered a double Post?  Technically, he did not double post here, as one of the commenters pointed out, but I'd like some clarification, as I've never seen this situation before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with an OP posting their questions outside of the Stack Exchange sites. More visibility to their issue is fine, when it's done in this manner. The only concern around double posting we as a SE community have, is when the exact same question is posted across multiple SE sites. This is discouraged and there's an option to close for what's called, cross-posting.

Even this can be somewhat tolerated if the OP has customized their question so that it's specifically targeted to the SE site within which they've posted it.

[image: ss#1]

For more on the subject the link in that pick discuss this a bit more.

- [Help Center > Asking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: Thank You Sir for your reply and screenshot.

Comment: This (meta-)question raises the point: the **Closing > Off-Topic** menu is ambiguous, and would be less so if it said, "This question has been posted on multiple Stack Exchange sites."

Comment: @G-Man - it's assuming that you've read the 2 URLs that it links to 8-), which specify this. If you do enough reviewing you'll come to understand that when they say "sites" they're referring to SE sites.

Comment: @slm Do you mean imply there are *other* sites than StackExchange on the internet? And on which SE sites could I ask a question on how to get to those supposedly existing sites? And if anything of interest is to be found there?

Comment: SE is the internet 8-)

Comment: @Anthon yes there are. They're collectively called "The Dark Web" and can be found using an onion.

Comment: @terdon It took me a while to understand your comment, especially the reference to the allium family member took a bit. I don't complete understand the need of use of The Dark Web, but then I grew up (as far as it got) in the Netherlands.